# Gradle "gradle-wrapper.properties" dynamic/configurable distributionUrl

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I have a gradle project, we use the gradlew.sh to build it.

The same GIT project/branch is used by two different teams.

The two teams have two different jenkins instances which contains the automation to build the project.

Now assuming that both the two teams jenkins automations clone and checkout same project and branch, **I want the to use two different values for the distributionUrl for the two teams**

*This because the first team cannot access to the distributionUrl of the second team and vice versa*

**Is there anyway to make this value dynamic, eg pass it from command line, use env variable or something else?**

I tried it all but it does not work, gradle is always taking the value specified in gradle-wrapper.properties distributionUrl, without giving me any change of overriding it.

**Please if my question is no clear or you want any further information feel free to let me know and I will update my question.**

Answer (score 3):

This is how you pass the distribution url on the command line:

```
./gradlew wrapper 
  --gradle-distribution-url=https://[your-artifactory]/gradle-distribution/gradle-4.10.3-bin.zip
  --gradle-distribution-sha256-sum=8626cbf206b4e201ade7b87779090690447054bc93f052954c78480fa6ed186e
```

source:  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper

Comment: This is the setting that controls the distribution used to *generate* the wrapper (ie gradlew wrapper), not the distribution that gets used when you run the wrapper (eg gradlew build)

Comment: @AdrianBaker 1) This command updates the `distributionUrl` in your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file. And that's the distribution used during `./gradlew ...` commands . 2) You are using `./gradlew wrapper`, therefore, the distribution from step 1) will apply. Try running twice `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-distribution-url=https://alex` and see what happens. If you want to be in control of the distro for generating a wrapper, I recommend using a centrally installed gradle distro e.g `/usr/local/bin/gradle`.

Comment: With an empty .gradle dir, the first thing that `./gradlew wrapper --gradle-distribution-url=https://alex` does is download the dist inside `gradle-wrapper.properties`. Which makes sense, --gradle-distribution-url is an arg to the wrapper task, and to interpret and run the wrapper task, gradle first needs to be downloaded from somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It is currently not possible to dynamically pass the distribution URL to the gradle wrapper. So I recommend doing this in Jenkins:

Put shell script step before the actual Gradle build step in Jenkins and and rewrite the `gradle-wrapper.properties` in that shell script step.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought too, actually there is a Gradle command which allow you to do this, without bash grep or any regex. Unfortunately this approach won't fully work for me, cause I got some logic within the automation which need the local repo to be aligned with the remote, so if I have local modification the process will fail...